# ¿Cómo capturo los datos de una petición Ajax en PHP?

Tags: php, php5, slim

Envió la data de la siguiente manera:

```
this.httpClient.post(
  this.url+'categorias/insertar',
  {
    "json": [
      {
        "nombre": this.categoria.nombre,
      }
    ]
  })
  .subscribe(
      data => {
          console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
      }
  );
```

Esta funciona bien, el problema esta en que en php no logro capturar el **json**:

```
$app->post('/categorias/insertar', function() use($db, $app){
    $json = $app->request->post('json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    echo json_encode($data);
});
```

Realizo un **`var_dump($app->request)`** y obtengo lo siguiente:
En el objeto se puede observar que llega la data, sin embargo no logro capturarla.

```
object(Slim\Http\Request)[43]
  protected 'env' => 
    object(Slim\Environment)[37]
      protected 'properties' => 
        array (size=22)
          'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'POST' (length=4)
          'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '::1' (length=3)
          'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/webapp-backend/index.php' (length=25)
          'PATH_INFO' => string '/categorias/insertar' (length=20)
          'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
          'SERVER_NAME' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
          'HTTP_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
          'CONTENT_LENGTH' => string '28' (length=2)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'application/json, text/plain, */*' (length=33)
          'HTTP_ORIGIN' => string 'http://localhost:4200' (length=21)
          'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' (length=114)
          'CONTENT_TYPE' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
          'HTTP_REFERER' => string 'http://localhost:4200/categoria' (length=31)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate, br' (length=17)
          'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'es-419,es;q=0.9' (length=15)
          'slim.url_scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
          'slim.input' => string '{"json":[{"nombre":"asda"}]}' (length=28)
          'slim.errors' => resource(24, stream)
          'slim.request.form_hash' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'slim.flash' => 
            object(Slim\Middleware\Flash)[19]
              ...
  public 'headers' => 
    object(Slim\Http\Headers)[44]
      protected 'data' => 
        array (size=10)
          'Host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'Connection' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
          'Content-Length' => string '28' (length=2)
          'Accept' => string 'application/json, text/plain, */*' (length=33)
          'Origin' => string 'http://localhost:4200' (length=21)
          'User-Agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' (length=114)
          'Content-Type' => string 'application/json' (length=16)
          'Referer' => string 'http://localhost:4200/categoria' (length=31)
          'Accept-Encoding' => string 'gzip, deflate, br' (length=17)
          'Accept-Language' => string 'es-419,es;q=0.9' (length=15)
  public 'cookies' => 
    object(Slim\Helper\Set)[46]
      protected 'data' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Comment: ¿Te diste cuenta que los datos se encuentran en la clave `slim.input` de `properties`? Tendrás entonces que acceder a esa clave. ¿Usas algún framework?, sería bueno que lo digas en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, me di cuenta de ello, pero aun así no encuentro como capturar esa clave. En **php** no uso ningún framework.

Comment: Sí estás usando un framework que es slim. Pero es slim 2 o slim 3?

Comment: Ya me extrañaba que no uses ningún framework. El comentario de @amenadiel confirma que sí. Debes revisar la documentación de Slim, donde imagino que explica la mejor forma de leer los datos que se envían al servidor desde Ajax.

Comment: @amenadiel tienes razon, **slim 2**

Comment: @A.Cedano revisando la documentación, **$method = $app->request()->getBody();** obtiene los datos.

Comment: ¿Lo resolviste entonces?, Pablo.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, busque la documentación como me dijiste. ¿Que hago? ¿Espero que respondan la pregunta?

Comment: Conviene que haya una respuesta para futuros usuarios. La puedes responder tú mismo indicando el enlace de la doc donde se explica cómo manejar los datos en el servidor, o @amenadiel. Si conociera `Slim` habría respondido, pero no voy a responder sobre algo que no conozco ni uso. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dependiendo de la librería que hace los requests, los datos pueden enviarse con distinto `content-type`.

jQuery por defecto envía los request con el header `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;` y por eso Slim2 puede capturarlos con

```
$json = $app->request->post('json');
```

Acá no hace falta hacer `json_decode` de lo que recibes. De por sí se parsea como un array.

El `httpClient` de angular envía los requests con `content-type: application/json` y por lo tanto los datos no llegan en el POST sino en el payload del body.

Cuando mandas la data en el body, tiene que viajar como string, no como objeto. Entonces tu petición debe ser:

```
this.httpClient.post(
  this.url+'categorias/insertar',
  {
    // conviertes el payload a un string
    JSON.stringify("json": [
      {
        "nombre": this.categoria.nombre,
      }
    ])
  })
  .subscribe(
      data => {
          console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
      }
  );
```

Y en el backend:

```
$app->post('/categorias/insertar', function() use($db, $app){
    $json = $app->request->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    echo json_encode($data);
});
```

Eso te responderá básicamente lo mismo que enviaste: `{"json":[{"nombre":"<NOMBRE X>"}]}`.

Pero si haces un var_dump a `$data` te dirá que es un array:

```
array(1) {
  ["json"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(21) "<NOMBRE X>"
    }
  }
}
```